# What does foo === +bar mean?

Tags: javascript, express

So I'm learning how to use express right now and there's a coding challenge that I got where I should download a zip file and do the things that I need to do. However, I'm looking through some of the code and I don't understand what some of it does. Like

```
const recipe = recipes.find( ({ id }) => {
return id === +recipeId; }
);
```

What does the +recipeId do?

recipeId is an integer. Like 2 or 3. What does the + in front of it do in this expression?
also recipes is an object that contains different recipes.

Comment: The unary `+` operator converts its operand to a number.

Comment: It does nothing in this case (assuming that `recipeId` really is a number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The + operator is used here to make sure that id is compared strictly with a number ie. recipeId. Just to make sure that even if recipeId is a string like "2", then first convert it to a number by using the unary operator + and then comparing it with id.

eg. suppose there arises a case where id=2 and and recipeId="2".

Then `id === recipeId` will return `false` as **=== operator also checks the type of the operands**.

**To evaluate it to true, both operands must be of same type and have same value**.
So, by using `+recipeId`, we first convert recipeId to a `number` and hence it will now  return `true`.